# Get rid of CMake warning 'Manually-specified variables were not used by the project'

Tags: cmake

What is the preferred way to just touch the variable, inside the `CMakeLists.txt`?

I've got a bunch of similar ExternalProjects that are called in a loop with the same variables. Some of the projects don't need specific variables.

Comment: What does 'touch a variable' mean?

Comment: @user3159253, it means to do with the variable something that has no effect. But it has to be robust, so it isn't confusing and it won't produce more warnings in the future CMake versions.

Comment: remove those unwanted variables (`-D<variable>`), when calling `cmake`. When not in use, remove them, than suppressing them.

Comment: @parasrish, can't do it.

Comment: The problem is that the unused detection in cmake is just not good enough. 
If you use the variable only in a conditional it is not flagged as used. 

if (DEFINED  SOME_CONDITION)   does not mark SOME_CONDITION as used.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could simply disable this warning all-together by passing `--no-warn-unused-cli` to CMake. See:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options

Touching the variable is explicitly not wanted according to one of the CMake authors:
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-February/042908.html

Nevertheless, for variables passed by `-DFOO=bar -DBAR=3 -DBAZ=true` you can add a line

```
set(ignoreMe "${FOO}${BAZ}${BAR}")
```

to one of your `CMakeLists.txt` which should be enough to suppress the warning.

Comment: The next email has an excellent "rebuttal" of the CMake author, recommended.